# How to map a 2d vector double to a string?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to map a 2d vector to a string; for instance, specifically I want to assign each individual row to its correct string, so like 1, 2, 7 to yes.

Also what if I want to assign a different key to the same value?

In row 1 and row 2 there's a value 2 and I want to assign yes to the 2 in row 1, and assign no to the 2 in row 2, how would I go about doing that?

row 1: {1, 2, 7} mapped to "Yes"

row 2: {2, 3, 4} mapped to "No"

row 3: {5, 7, 8} mapped to "Yes"

My 2D vector:

```
 int N = 3;
 int M = 3;
vector<vector<double>> matrix2d(N, vector<double>(M));
```

My code for the first row does not work:

```
map < vector<double>, string > map_of_strings;
map_of_strings = {{matrix2d[0][0], matrix2d[0][1], matrix2d[0][2]}, "yes"};
```

The error msg that I receive is:

```
1>d:\practice\finalproject\finalproject\source.cpp(118): error C2552: 'map_of_strings' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
```

Comment: Habitually, `matrix2d[0]` represents the first row ...

Comment: Oh sorry I fixed it

Comment: I added the error msg that I get

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo  Don't have that in my code

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. I now see that you use a standard map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a single value, you need to proceed this way:

```
map_of_strings [{matrix2d[0][0], matrix2d[1][0], matrix2d[2][0]}] = "yes";
```

or this way:

```
map_of_strings [{1, 2, 7}] ="yes";
```

Then, you can check what's in for a given combination:

```
cout << map_of_strings [{matrix2d[0][0], matrix2d[1][0], matrix2d[2][0]}] << endl;
```

If you want to initialize your map with several values, you need to provide several couple { key, value } within an enclosing curly brace:

```
map < vector<double>, string > map_of_strings = { {{1, 2, 7},"yes"}, 
                                                  {{2, 3, 4},"no"},
                                                  {{5, 7, 8},"yes"} };
```

Comment: After correction of the question: `map_of_strings[matrix2d[0]] = "yes";`

Comment: @Damien yes, this is an even faster way !

Comment: @Christophe Thank you! When I tried your code I get an error for the first ' { ' after map_of_strings and I highlighted over it, it says that "expected an expression"

Comment: @NoobCoder Could you run it in the meantime ?  I've tested it here and have no problem: https://ideone.com/gwQE0E Which compiler and version do you use ?

Comment: @Christophe Visual Studios 2012

Comment: @Damien I did `map_of_strings[matrix2d[0]] = "yes";`, but how it won't let me access the individual element in the map of matrix2d in the first row `cout << map_of_strings[matrix2d[0][1]];`

Comment: @Damien Never mind I fixed it, but when I did `cout << map_of_strings[{matrix2d[0][1]}];`, it's not printing anything

Comment: @NoobCoder Unfortunately [MSVC2012 did not provide full support for C++11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) and important things like initializer lists were missing. So I fear that you'd need to go via vectors as you did with `map_of_strings[matrix2d[0]]`.  Caution:  `map_of_strings[matrix2d[0][1]]`will not work, because `matrix2d[0][1]` is a simple double and not a vector.

Comment: @NoobCoder Did you test `cout << map_of_strings[matrix2d[0]]` ?